# Package name in module code

Tags: perl, variables, package, scope, perl-module

## Short version

Is it possible to access variables from a module declared as `our` using unqualified names within the `BEGIN` code block, but using qualified names outside? In particular, can this be done *without* explicitely naming the package in the module file?

## Example

Let `demomod.pm` be

```
use strict;
use warnings;    
package demomod;
our $foo;
BEGIN { $foo = 42; }
1;
```

and `demoscript.pl` be

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN { @INC = ('.', @INC); }
use demomod;
print $demomod::foo."\n";
```

In this case, all names agree, and everything works as it should. Is there a way to omit the line `package demomod;` from the `demomod.pm` code and still let this work?

## Motivation

The reason why I'm asking is because I encountered something along these lines during a recent upgrade of [Foswiki](http://www.foswiki.org/). That software has a module [`Foswiki.pm`](http://trac.foswiki.org/browser/tags/FoswikiRelease01x01x06/core/lib/Foswiki.pm) <s>which does not have a `package` line</s> *(EDIT: seems the `package` line only got lost in my local copy, for reasons unknown)*. It [declares](http://trac.foswiki.org/browser/tags/FoswikiRelease01x01x06/core/lib/Foswiki.pm#L67) and [initializes](http://trac.foswiki.org/browser/tags/FoswikiRelease01x01x06/core/lib/Foswiki.pm#L611) a variable `$engine` like in my example. There also is a CGI script called [`view`](http://trac.foswiki.org/browser/tags/FoswikiRelease01x01x06/core/bin/view) which sets `@INC` and then does `use Foswiki ();` followed by `$Foswiki::engine->run()`. This last line always fails for me due to the variable not being initialized:

```
Can't call method "run" on an undefined value at …/view
```

In the `BEGIN` block of the module, `$engine` is set correctly but `$Foswiki::engine` apparently is not. So it looks like there were two variables here, one qualified and a different one unqualified.

All that code apparently works for others, and a previous version used to work for me as well, <s>without a `package` line either</s>. So while I try to understand how this broke, I also try to understand how this could work before, without that line in place. Is there some mechanism that would make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no `package` statement in your code then any package variables will be declared into the `main` package. So no, you cannot do what you describe.

If you look at line 2 of the `Foswiki` code that you linked, you will see that it *does* have a package statement.

Comment: OK, you are right about that line being present in the upstream sources. I wrongly assumed my local copy to be identical. Still trying to figure out where that line went in my copy. Strange, but definitely a local problem.